# Help with MS ACCESS database structure

Tags: database, ms-access

Help with MS ACCESS database structure

Using MS Acess Database 200 (*.mdb). I am trying to create a little databse app for myself for storing hoto knowledge about a number of our apps.

We currently have three applications, with a number of versions amongest each

I would like have a search able database where i can search for knowledge using keywords, title, app, or version

Would the following be correct?

### Apps

id
app

### verions

id
appId
version

### knowledge

id
versionId
question
answer

### keywords

id
knowledgeId
keyword

Comment: Sorry about the format, i am pretty new to the formatting. The bold words are the table names, and the non bold words, are the fields, and it looks like they are separated by spaces (which should have been new lines)

Comment: In SO, you can use 2 spaces for a line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.  Are you trying to get a database up and running that meets your needs? Or is it the intellectual challenge of making this thing that interests you?

If you want to make this database as a learning experience, then you're off to a good start.  You can put forms, reports, tables, and of course some VBA. You'll probably need some more ID fields though.  But the beauty of Access is that you can change the design relatively easily as you go.

If you already know your VBA or have other things to do, then there's a wide variety of freeware apps that will meet your needs.  I googled "tree notes software" and found this: http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Information_Management/Notes_Management_Tools/Tree_Notes.html.  If you look at the screenshot, you'll see how you can put in software, versions, questions, etc.  I haven't tried this, but I assume you can search for specific keywords. (This isn't the only Personal Information Manager of its kind.  Search for one that suits you best).

Comment: Actually, I will be connecting to this via an App created using Delphi (Object Pascal).  So, I am not worried about anything other than getting the fields corrected. I guess what i am asking, is whether or not I have my relationships correct?

Comment: I'm no expert in DB design, but I don't think the keyword table is linked properly. Right now, you have a set of keywords for each app, but you don't link the keywords to individual questions in the knowledge table. Maybe add another table that links each keyword to multiple records in the knowledge table? This table would be hidden to you during normal use and would be updated automatically in the background.

Comment: Hmmmm, For each App, there is (n) versions, for each version there is (n) knowledge records (questions), and for each knowledge question, there is (n) keywords.  I may be wrong, but this seems logical to me.....but, i wouldn't have this question on here if i thought i was 100% right - <Smile>

Comment: "for each knowledge question, there is (n) keywords" Exactly, but the foreign key (keywords.id) in your keyword table doesn't link to the questions, it links to apps.id.  in other words, you are setting assigning keywords to the apps, not the questions.  Make sense?

Comment: That makes more sense then. I thought knowledgeid was the primary key for that table. You may want to rename all the primary keys accordingly, like version.id to version.versionid and knowledge.id to knowledge.knowledgeid. But if it works for you as is, go with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over keywords (like who can add a new keyword), you may need a Keywords table, so you can try and control duplicates: (access, Access, MS Access). A KnowledgeKeywords table would be needed to create a many-to-many relationship between Knowledge and Keywords.

**knowledge**
id versionId question answer

**knowledgekeywords**
id knowledgeId keywordid

**keywords**
id  keyword

Comment: I like your suggestion, but it doesn't qualify as an answer to my question of whether or not my structuring above is correct. What you offer is an addition (a good one) rather than an answer.  No one is really said whether or not my structure above is good or not. What do you think? One claims my Kewords tanle is not properly linked. I think it is. What do you think. Yes, the keywords could be duplicated without your extension, but other than that?